# Attr_accessor in Node Class

Tags: ruby, linked-list

I understand that in Ruby, the `attr_accessor` key simply creates `getter/setter` methods.
For example,

`attr_accessor :data`

```
def data=(value)
  @data = value
end

def data
  @data
end
```

So, if this were the case, for a `Node` class why would I need to create an `initialize` method?

Ex:

```
def initialize(data, next_node)
 @data = data;
 @next_node = next_node;
```

Couldn't I just write `att_accessor :data, next_node`?

Comment: This is likely going to result in an opinionated answer - constructors are used to define an interface to your class, ie the data that it needs to be instantiated.  Only you can really define what that constructor needs to be based on who and what it works with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an `initialize` method you can write:

```
node = Node.new('foo', node)
```

Without (and only with `attr_accessor`) you need to write:

```
node = Node.new
node.data = 'foo'
node.next_node = node
```

To answer your question: There is no need for an `initialize` method, but it would be more convenient to use.

Comment: It's not just more convenient, it's also arguably more correct. In the latter case, the object is useless when instantiated. But an object should be fully initialized, ready to be used, with all its invariants fulfilled, when it is constructed. In the latter case, `Node` relis on some random other code to fulfil its own invariants.